# Django render page with context does not work

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I like to re-render my page, after a document was uploaded using Django. I'd like to change `context['FileName'] = 'Test'` to `context['FileName'] = 'Test2'` in the HTML page. But it does not work and I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong here.

views.py:

```
     def UploadView (request): 
     context = {}
     
    #Generate Language Selection 
     
     context['FileName'] = 'Test'
     if request.method == "POST":
         if not(request.FILES=={}):
                date_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                date_time = date_time.strftime('%Y%m%d_%H_%M')
               
                #uploaded_file = request.FILES["uploaded_file"]          
                uploaded_file = request.FILES.get('file')
                document = Document(
                file_title = request.user.user_unique_key,
                uploaded_file = uploaded_file,
                date_time = date_time,               
                )
                document.save()
                file_path = document.uploaded_file.file.name
                file_name = uploaded_file.name
                context['FileName']='Test2'; 
                return render(request,"UPLOAD.html",context)
     return render(request, "UPLOAD.html", context)
```

Html file:

```html
<h6><font color="red">{{FileName}}</font></h6>
```

Comment: Do you get any error or simply not getting desired output? I mean context value does not work. Does the file successfully save in `Document` model?

Comment: Do you have any files sent? Maybe this expression is always `True`: `request.FILES=={}`. Print/debug yourself `request.FILES` just before condition.

Comment: everything works fine, the document has been saved successfully, but when it comes to rendering, no update is visible, it just keeps value "Test" in the HTML page.